# React: rendering name-value pairs as React.FC

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple name-value pair defined as an interface `NameValuePair`.

```
interface NameValuePair {
    [key: number]: string; 
}
```

Using this interface, `React.useEffect` is initializing the state values like

```
const NameValuePairFC = () => {
    const [nameValuePairs, setNameValuePairs] = React.useState<NameValuePair>();
     
     React.useEffect(() => {        
         const tempNameValueMap: NameValuePair = {};
         tempNameValueMap[0] = "Zero";
         tempNameValueMap[1] = "One";
         tempNameValueMap[2] = "Two";
         setNameValuePairs(tempNameValueMap);
     }, [nameValuePairs]);
 
     return (
       <div className="content">
       Rendering name value pairs
           {          
               Object.keys(nameValuePairs).map((key) => {
                   const nv = nameValuePairs[key];       
                   console.log("name: " + key + "; value: " + nv[key]);
       
                   <div key={key}>
                       Key: {key} and value: {nv[key]}
                   </div>;
               })
           };   
       </div>
     );
};
```

I see that nothing got printed at the console and no fragment rendered.
I am expecting to print the 3 name value pairs `0: Zero, 1: One, 2: Two` defined and not sure what am I doing wrong.
Please let me know. I have put it in [codepen](https://codepen.io/rajsenthil/pen/mdmKMqj) that I am trying to do.

Comment: After posting this I made some improvements to the code and could see the console out iterating through the key:value pairs.

Comment: Also, considering you have `const nv = nameValuePairs[key];` then `nv[key]` is invalid as you're basically trying to do `"Zero"[0]`. You should be using `nv` directly from there as it holds the actual value.

Comment: That's right @zhulien. I updated the codepen as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `nameValuePairs` is always of default value. The `useEffect` is not executed, therefore the state is not updated. Try with an petty dependency array.

Also, you don’t return anything from the `map` function. Add a `return` statement. So your code won't render the pairs.

Your code should look like this:

```
interface NameValuePair {
    [key: number]: string;
}

const NameValuePairFC = () => {
    const [nameValuePairs, setNameValuePairs] = React.useState<NameValuePair>();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const tempNameValueMap: NameValuePair = {};
        tempNameValueMap[0] = "Zero";
        tempNameValueMap[1] = "One";
        tempNameValueMap[2] = "Two";
        setNameValuePairs(tempNameValueMap);
    }, []); // empty dependency array added, `useEffect` executed once, on first render

    return (
        <div className="content">
            Rendering name value pairs
            {nameValuePairs &&
                Object.keys(nameValuePairs).map((value, index, array) => {
                    console.log(
                        "NameValuePairFC name: " + index + "; value: " + nameValuePairs[index]
                    );
                    return (<div key={index}> // return statement added
                        Key: {index} and value: {nameValuePairs[index]}
                    </div>)
                })}
            ;
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<NameValuePairFC />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you @Riwen, could you please elaborate or point to an example for adding a return statement for map function.

Comment: Yes, with return from map function, it worked. Thanks for the quick reposnse with solution. It is quite helpful. You saved my day.